# fileinfo not restricting pdf only

Tags: php, fileinfo

I am using the below script to validate if the uploaded files are pdf and if it is send it with phpmailer. It send the email but there is no attachment. Also, it allows me to attach non pdf files as well. Please help.

```
ob_start();
require("class.phpmailer.php");

if(isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])){
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime=finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
if($mime=='application/pdf'){

$message = "some message";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From     = ('sample@youdomain.net');
$mail->AddAddress=('sample@youdomain.net');
$mail->Subject  = "Submitted files";
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

foreach($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] as $upload) 
if(!empty($upload)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($upload);
}
$mail->Send();

header("Location: thankyou.php");
exit();     
}}
```

Comment: The script as-is won't do anything because of syntax errors.

Comment: @VolkerK I have updated my script as advise but now I am not receiving the email anymore even when a pdf file is attached.  please help. thx.

Comment: XDebug + netbeans is an easy to install debug/frontend combo for php and can help you to pin-point the problem: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have:

```
if( ... ) { 
    ...
    if($mime=='application/pdf') {
    }
}
// some code you want to be executed
// only if the mime type is application/pdf
```

But you want:

```
if (...) {
  ..
  if ($mime=='application/pdf') {
        // place the code you want to be executed
        // only if the mime type is application/pdf
        // here - before the closing }
    }
}
```